# Strange behavior using SO_SNDBUF on non-blocking TCP socket under windows

Tags: tcp, buffer, send, nonblocking

I'm trying to lower the send buffer size on my non-blocking TCP socket so that I can properly display an upload progress bar but I'm seeing some strange behavior.

I am creating a non-blocking TCP socketed, setting SO_SNDBUF to 1024, verifying that is is set properly, then connecting (tried this before and after call to connect with no difference).

The problem is, when my app actually comes around and calls send (sending about 2MB) rather than returning that around 1024 bytes were sent, the send call apparently accepts all the data and returns a sent value of 2 MB (exactly what I passed in). Everything operates properly (this is an HTTP PUT and i get a response, etc) but what I end up displaying in my progress bar is the upload sitting at 100% for about 30 seconds then the response coming in.

I have verified that if I stop before getting the response the upload does not complete so it's not like it just uploaded really fast and then the server stalled... Any ideas? Does windows even look at this setting?

Comment: SO_SNDBUF is the maximum size of your send buffer ... trying to send 2MB at once with 1 kB buffer sounds a bit strange to me. You should probably either increase your send buffer to more than 2 MB or make sends smaller than 1kb. I think you mistakenly believe that setting SO_SNDBUF will "cut" your 2 MB in 1 kB segments and send them one by one, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: My impression is that it's supposed to limit the amount of data that can be queued at any time though, right. Basically I just need an indicator for how much data has actually been transmitted (as opposed to queued). The size of the buffer isn't really relevant to me, I just wanted to pick something small enough that I should see some granularity. Is there a better way to do this? HTTP doesn't have any sort of built-in mid-upload ACK afaik.

Comment: Yes it is that. If you can queue only 1kB, you can't send 2MB. Why it pretends it did send 2 MB is another problem. Keep in mind that whatever you do, TCP may very well combine or split your packets behind your back (see Nagle). You should split your sends by yourself, I guess that in your case something between 10 and 50 kB should do. To see the upload going on, use Wireshark or a proxy like Fiddler2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does look at this setting, but the setting is not working as you expect it to be.
When you're setting the size of those buffers, you're actually setting the size of the buffers on the actuall NIC you're communicating with, thus determining the size of the packets that are going out.

What you need to know about Windows, is that there is a buffer between your calling code and the actuall NIC, and I'm not sure that you can control the size of that. What happens if when you call the Send operation on your socket, you're dumping the data in that socket, and the Kernel of Windows will perform small step by step sends on the NIC using the data in the buffer.

This means that the code will actually report 2MB beeing 'sent', but this just means that your 2MB of data has been successfully written in the internal buffer, and it does not mean/guarantee that the data has already been sent.

I've been working on similar projects with video streaming and tcp communications, and this information is somewhere available on the MSDN Forums and technet, but it requires some really detailed searching on how it all actually works.

Answer (score 2):

I observed the same thing on Windows, using Java non-blocking channel.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214397

> If necessary, Winsock can buffer significantly more than the SO_SNDBUF buffer size.

This makes sense; the send is initiated by a program on local machine, which is presumed to be cooperative and not hostile. If kernel has enough memory, there's no point to reject the send data; some one must buffer it anyway. (Receive buffer is for the remote program, which may be hostile)

Kernel does have limits on this buffering of send data. I'm making a server socket, and kernel accepts at most 128K per send; not like 2MB in your example which is for a client socket.

Also according to the same article, kernel only buffer 2 sends; next non-blocking send should return immediately reporting 0 bytes written. So if we only send small amount of data each time, the program will be throttled by the receiving end, and your progress indicator would work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The setting does not affect anything on the NIC; it is the Kernel buffer that is affected. It defaults to 8k for both Send and Receive.

The reason for the behavior you are seeing is this: the send buffer size is NOT the limit of the amount you can sent at one time, it is the "nominal" buffer size. It really only affects subsequent sends when there is still data in the buffer waiting to be sent.

For example:

1. Set the send buffer to 101 bytes
2. Send 10 bytes, it will be buffered
3. Send 10 more bytes, it will be buffered
4. ...continue until the buffer has 100 bytes in it
5. Send 10 more bytes

   At this point WinSock uses some logic to determine whether to accept the new 10 bytes (and make the buffer 110 bytes) or block. I don't recall the behavior exactly but it is on MSDN.
6. Send 10 more bytes

This last one will definately block until some buffer space is available.

So, in essence, the send buffer is sizeable and:

- WinSock will always accept a send of almost any size of the buffer is empty
- If the buffer has data and a write will overflow, there is some logic to determine whether to accept/reject
- If the buffer is full or overflowed, it will not accept the new send

Sorry for the vagueness and lack of links; I'm in a bit of a hurry but happened to remember these details from a network product I wrote a while back.